# gradle/wrapper: utime impossible: Operation not permitted after run "flutter doctor"

Tags: flutter, gradle, wrapper

I created a new flutter project and I executed the command

> flutter doctor

It returns me the following error.

/usr/bin/tar: gradle/wrapper: utime impossible: Operation not allowed

/usr/bin/tar: gradle/wrapper: mode cannot be changed to rwxr-xr-x: Operation not allowed

/usr/bin/tar: gradle: utime impossible: Operation not allowed

/usr/bin/tar: gradle: mode cannot be changed to rwxr-xr-x: Operation not allowed

/usr/bin/tar: Shutdown with failure code due to previous errors

To solve the problem I accode all rights to the file in question "usr/bin/tar". But the problem still persists. After I installed gradle/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjsP8.png)wrapper but the problem persists

I am using Fedora as my operating system

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Ubuntu:

I deleted the /flutter/bin/cache directory. Then I could run

> flutter doctor

and

> flutter pub get

without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, using ubuntu.

I used the command `sudo snap install flutter --classic`
then I logged in as root and performed `flutter doctor`, it was ok.